# Is there Google Ads manager - read only link?

Tags: google-ads-api

I am trying to build Google ads API in python.
I have the token and access but now I need to link accounts to my MCC account.
But the "Link existing accounts" give me full access. I only need read only.
Is there read only "Link existing accounts"?

Thanks,
Tal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no such option.

However, if your goal is to have read-only API access to a specific account you can still achieve that by adding a user (i.e. Google account) with [read-only access](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/9978556) to that account and then generating OAuth2 credentials for that user. You do not need to use an manager account / MCC to be able to utilize the Google Ads API.